# who can tell me why can this function work?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, operators, swap

```
function swap(&$a,&$b)
{

    $a=$a^$b;
    $b=$a^$b;
    $a=$a^$b;

}
```

RT，why it can swap two numbers or strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called XOR Swap. XOR has interesting property.

- A XOR A = 0
- A XOR 0 = A

So basically,

```
$a = $a ^ $b;
$b = $a ^ $b;  // which is $b = a XOR b XOR b = a
$a = $a ^ $b;  // which is $a = a XOR b XOR a = b
```

However, I would not advise you to use XOR swap. It does not perform as good as swap using temporary variable. If everyone interest in this lovely magical XOR operator, there are a few interesting algorithms that build on this same concept:

- [XOR Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list)
- [XOR Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)

Comment: thx very much! I know ^ means xor,but I didn't know $b can be changed to that form.thx again

Answer (score 0):

If your C/C++ concepts are clear, you can understand it simply.

**^ working as XOR** (Hope you have gone through a bit about Digital Electronics OR, AND etc)

**Assume it in simple manner**

```
$a=20;
$b=30;

function swap($a,$b) {
$a=$a*$b;
$b=$a/$b;
$a=$a/$b;
}
```

**Output:** $a=30 and $b=20

You can use it in many ways like

```
function swap($a,$b) {
$a=$a+$b;
$b=$a-$b;
$a=$a-$b;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your nice answer! I have understand it